# How to unpublish a page and still keep a draft?

Tags: publish, draft, customization

I have a holiday sale page that no longer applies as the holidays have past.

- I want to keep the page for future design reference.
- I do not want the page to be accessible from the Internet.

I tried:

- Setting the page status to `Pending Review`
- Setting the page status to `Draft`

Neither of these status changes seem to have any effect as the page is still visible at the URL. I am not even sure why these settings exist for pages.

I could password protect or set the page to private, but neither option unpublishes the page.

I could do a 301 redirect, but I would prefer not to use this method.  ([SEO impact of 301 redirects.](https://moz.com/blog/accidental-seo-tests-how-301-redirects-are-likely-impacting-your-brand))

Is there no other option?

Comment: You are logged as admin. If you were not what would you get?

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information here - have you tested when logged out? Are you using a caching plugin? What's your hosting setup?

Comment: @prosti You are right.  When I logged out the URL generated a 404. Why can I see the page when logged in?  Is this documented somewhere in the codex?

Comment: @nueverest I tried to answer the best I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I logged out the URL generated a 404.

Correct.

> Why can I see the page when logged in? Is this documented somewhere in the codex?

I think this is something that [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status) has but some parts are still not written, like this part for [draft](https://codex.wordpress.org/index.php?title=Post_Status&action=edit&section=5).
In the case of **draft** post your permalink will look like this:

```
?p=2898&preview=true
```

And it is not available when you are not logged out as you noted — *404 error page* is what you will get.

The same error you will get also for the **pending review** status when you are not logged in, but the permalink will be the same as for the **published** post if you are logged in.